# Distinct values from two columns

Tags: sql

This is the query which I am using to get the distinct values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LOGIN_BY,
    RECEIVED_BY
FROM SAMPLE
```

My requirement is I need the distinct values of both the columns as a single output. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc. ? Also, we would need to see what query you have tried before asking this question.

Comment: Your query will give you the distinct _combinations_ of LOGIN_BY and RECEIVED_BY. If this is not what you want you should try to clarify your desired output in the question; preferably with some sample data.

Comment: What will be the case if distinct `LOGIN_BY` returns 20 values and distinct `RECEIVED_BY` returns 30 values? Can we fill the NULL or Empty for the remaining values?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(SELECT DISTINCT LOGIN_BY as ID from sample )
union all
(Select Distinct RECEIVED_BY as ID FROM SAMPLE)
```

Comment: @jpw Yes You are right .. Thanks .. I edited the answer

Comment: @Richard Bosco .. Please accept the answer and upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
select distinct a from (
  select
    distinct LOGIN_BY as a
  from
    SAMPLE
  union
  select
    distinct RECEIVED_BY as a
  from
    SAMPLE
);
```

This works for me on an Oracle database.